# Rewrite $2^{x-6} + 2^x$ as $A \cdot 2^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I simply don't understand how to rewrite $$2^{x-6} + 2^x =A\cdot 2^x$$ for some $A.$

I can work up to a certain point but after that, I'm lost. Here is my work:

$$2^{x-6}+2^x$$
$$\to 2^x \cdot 2^{-6} + 2^x$$
$$\to 2^x \cdot \frac1{64} + 2^x$$

After that, I don't know what to do. Could someone please help me understand how to solve this?

Comment: You can take $2^x$ common from both terms.

Comment: Recall that $(a+b)c = ac+bc$ and vice versa... including when $b$ happened to be equal to $1$ and not visible... i.e. that $ac+c = (a+1)c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there! Now all we have to do is use the distributive rule, which gives $$2^x*1/64+2^x = 2^x*(1+1/64) = 65/64 * 2^x$$
Therefore, $A = 65/64$

Comment: Sorry if the fractions in this form looks a bit bad.

Comment: If you want, you can recheck some help pages about MathJax, *e.g.*, [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3):

The task is to factor out $2^x$. Note that $2^{x-6} = 2^{-6} \cdot 2^x $, and similarly $2^x = 1\cdot 2^x $, therefore

$$2^{x-6} + 2^x = (2^{-6} +1)  \cdot 2^x = A \cdot 2^x$$

for $A = 2^{-6} + 1$.